# Learn Regex, match word inside function

Tags: regex

I learn Regex and I try to match some things only inside function.

```
test() {
    stack();
    overflow;
    stack;
    overflow();
}
```

I want to match all **stack** words only inside the function.

My idea to do it:

1) Look behind if `() {` exists. `(?<=\(\) {)`

2) Go to character by character (also whitespaces) and check:

Is the first character `s`?

If yes, ahead to: Is the second character `t`? etc.

If no, ahead to next character and check again: Is the first character `s`?

I also know `\K` it disappears what is already matched.

I don't know how to realize it.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, if you want to match all **stack** words, you might also use an optional capturing group and make use of the `\G` anchor.

```
(?:[^\s()]+\(\)\h*{(?=[^{}]+\r?\n}$)|\G(?!^))\r?\n\h+(stack\b)?\S*
```

*About the pattern*

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^\s()]+\(\)\h*{` Match the function name, `()` and `{`
  - `(?=[^{}]+\r?\n}$)` Assert what follows is `}` at the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\r?\n\h+` Match newline and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(stack\b)?\S* Optionally capture`stack` followed by 0+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G06bcW/1)

Answer (score 0):

`(?m)(?:\(\s*\)\s*{(?=[^{}]*})|(?!^)\G)(?s:(?![{}]).)*?\K\bst.*?(?=\h*$)`

https://regex101.com/r/UOYxUB/1

```
 (?m)
 (?:
      \( \s* \) \s* {  
      (?= [^{}]* } )

   |  (?! ^ )
      \G 
 )
 (?s:
      (?! [{}] )
      . 
 )*?
 \K 
 \b 
 st .*? 
 (?= \h* $ )
```